# How can I update status with photo in android?

Tags: android, facebook, photo, status

Is it possible to update status with photo? It seems that only text can be posted by update status and only photo can be uploaded without text. I searched internet, but I couldn't get any hint. Please let me know if it is possible and if then, how I can do it. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a silly question, but through the `Facebook app`, or through another program/`API`?

Comment: yes, it is through api.

Answer (score 2):

you may install a facebook app and then you can update the status with photo ....jst click on upload photo in the app